# Google Cloud project resources removed after trial periode

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I used Google Cloud for 1 year and after that I stopped using it for almost a year.

Now I want to use it again, but the resources (VM'S, Snapshots, etc) are removed by Google. Accordering to Google, all resources will be removed after the trial periode has been exceeded by 30 day's.

Is is possible to file a restore request (whole project, or at least a VM or Snapshot? Paid, or unpaid restore doesn't matter for me.

Please advice.

Thank you.

upgraded my account to a paid account (pay as you go). But still no resources.
Only my project name is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GCP Free Tier documentation](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end) is very clear in this aspect, as it states in the "Recovering data" section:

> **Recovering Data**
>
> Contact Google Billing Support to export any data you stored in GCP services (other than on Compute Engine) during your trial period. Your data and resources are only available for 30 days after the free trial ends.

Maybe a couple days after the 30 days you would still have a chance to request it and have it done, but more than that is very unlikely. This kind of deadlines are in place to protect and free some of the shared resources of GCP.

Your only realistic possibility here is [contacting GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/support/), explain your situation and hope that something could be recovered, but understand that it's very unlikely.

Comment: contacted them, but the data is automatically removed after 30 day's.
Really nog other way?

Comment: If they can't reach it, then it's no way to recover it, sorry